# How to edit CSS and HTML in frameworks such as Hexo using Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, hexo

I am new to `Node.js` and decided to try to make a blog website using [Hexo](http://hexo.io/). The problem I am having is trying to edit the main style sheet and index files to include a new web font (or any editing in general).

The way I figured it would work is I would make the change and the server would pick it, such as with the `/themes folder` as stated in the docs. Though this is not the case and it doesn't seem like you can edit the CSS directly.

How do I edit the main CSS and index in such frameworks as these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hexo.io used  [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/), you can look at the documentation.

I tried to make changes to the default theme and worked.

by examples in the path: themes \ landscape \ source \ css - style.styl

Answer (score 1):

In Hexo, the theme is responsible for rendering and styling the content in HTML. The theme can decide what preprocessor (for CSS and HTML templating) to use.

`landscape` is using [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/) for CSS and [EJS](https://github.com/tj/ejs) (note it is 1.0) for templating.
You have to `npm install hexo-renderer-ejs hexo-renderer-stylus` for it to work.

There are [other renderers](https://github.com/hexojs?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=renderer) but they are less popular.